# Exposure details for this now (in)famous image from Lowell Observatory?

Tags: observational-astronomy, artificial-satellite, identify-this-object

IAU's announcement 19035 [IAU Statement on Satellite Constellations, 03 June 2019](https://www.iau.org/news/announcements/detail/ann19035/) links to 19035a [Trails made by Starlink satellites](https://www.iau.org/public/images/detail/ann19035a/) which contains the image shown below.

**Question:** Is it possible to track down the exact start time and exposure duration for this image, and which telescope was used?

[image: NGC 5353/4 galaxy group + Starlink satellites, Lowell Observatory, ann19035a]

> An image of the NGC 5353/4 galaxy group made with a telescope at Lowell Observatory in Arizona, USA on the night of Saturday 25 May 2019. The diagonal lines running across the image are trails of reflected light left by more than 25 of the 60 recently launched Starlink satellites as they passed through the telescope’s field of view.
>
> Although this image serves as an illustration of the impact of reflections from satellite constellations, please note that the density of these satellites is significantly higher in the days after launch (as seen here) and also that the satellites will diminish in brightness as they reach their final orbital altitude.
>
> Credit: Victoria Girgis/Lowell Observatory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was the one operating the telescope at the time! I was using our 11 inch telescope fitted with a 1 MP MallinCam camera. The image was taken at 9:21 pm with a 25 second exposure.

Comment: That's pretty darn cool, thank you for your reply! Okay I'll go have fun with [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) and some archived TLEs.  I don't see an 11-inch [here](https://lowell.edu/giovale-open-deck-observatory/telescopes/) but I suppose those are for public outreach rather than research.